# AWS full access policy for Application Load Balancer

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

Right now, my AWS account has the following policies:

- AmazonEC2FullAccess
- AmazonSQSFullAccess
- AmazonS3FullAccess
- AmazonAPIGatewayInvokeFullAccess
- CloudWatchFullAccess
- AmazonKinesisFullAccess
- AmazonRekognitionFullAccess
- AmazonKinesisVideoStreamsFullAccess
- AmazonKinesisFirehoseFullAccess
- AmazonSNSFullAccess

In order to setup an ‘application load balancer’ with auto scaling group, target group, subnets in a VPC, what are the other policies that I would require?

Answer (score -1):

```
AmazonVPCFullAccess,
AutoScalingFullAccess,
Application Load Balancer:
AssumeRolePolicyDocument={
    "Version": "2008-10-17",
    "Statement": [{
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Principal": {"Service": ["ecs.amazonaws.com", "application-autoscaling.amazonaws.com"]},
        "Action": ["sts:AssumeRole"]
    }]
},
with ManagedPolicyArns
["arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/service-role/AmazonEC2ContainerServiceRole",
   "arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/service-role/AmazonEC2ContainerServiceAutoscaleRole"]
```

It may be better to write custom policies with the least privilege access